# var values argued into a callback from outside it:

Tags: java

Eclipse redlines `width, height, width, height` in the doSomething() arg list in the callback.  Little red X in the left margin; says:

```
Multiple markers at this line
 - Cannot refer to a non-final variable height inside an inner class defined in a different 
  method
 - Cannot refer to a non-final variable width inside an inner class defined in a different 
  method
 - Cannot refer to a non-final variable width inside an inner class defined in a different 
  method
 - Cannot refer to a non-final variable height inside an inner class defined in a different 
  method
```

Obviously I don't want to waste cycles by repeating `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()` to obtain those values repeatedly from inside the `holder` callback or from inside the `doSomething()`.

This entire snip is inside of one class.

Thanks for any help.

```
  ... 

  Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();   
  int width = display.getWidth();  
  int height = display.getHeight(); 

  ... 

  final GL10 gl = (GL10) eglContext.getGL();  
  final Handler handler = new Handler();  
  SurfaceHolder holder = view.getHolder(); 
  holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_GPU);  

  int w = 0; 
  int h = 0; 
  int x = 0; 
  int y = 0; 

  int b[] = new int[w * (y + h)]; 
  int bt[] = new int[w * h]; 
  IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.wrap(b); 
  ib.position(0); 
  gl.glReadPixels(x, 0, w, y + h, GL10.GL_RGBA,GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,ib); 

  ...

  holder.addCallback(new Callback() { 
    private EGLSurface surface;  
    private Runnable painter;  

    @Override  
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {  
      painter = new Runnable() {  
        @Override  
        public void run() {  
          doSomething(width, height, width, height, gl); 
        }  
      };  
      handler.post(painter);  
    }  
  }); //Callback ends. 
} 

private void doSomething(int x, int y, int w, int h, GL10 gl) {  
  // do something  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the **final** keyword on the **width** and **height** parameters of the **surfaceChanged(...)** method to make them accessible to the **run()** method in the **painter** *Runnable* and get rid of the compiler error.

```
@Override  
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, final int width, final int height) {  
  painter = new Runnable() {  
    @Override  
    public void run() {  
      doSomething(width, height, width, height, gl); 
    }  
  };  
  handler.post(painter);  
}
```

This is avoidable in Java 8 because it would consider **width** and **height** to be *effectively final*.

Taking the Java 8 thought to it's logical extension with Lambda Expressions yields more concise code:

```
@Override  
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {  
  painter = () -> {  
      doSomething(width, height, width, height, gl);
  };  
  handler.post(painter);  
}
```